# registros masivos con el mismo formulario asp.net

Tags: sql-server, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

tengo un problema con asp.net estoy trabajando con entity framework y tengo un proyecto en el cual necesito agregar otros registros sin salir del formulario y añadiendolo a la misma vista como lo indico en la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al darle en el '+' que se me agregen mas input como agregar un nuevo cheque pero que al darle guardar sean registros distintos en la base de datos sql. estoy trabajano con el crud generado por el visual studio por favoor ayuda!!! no se si exista un Script o algo parecido para realizarlo

Comment: Como implementas ese + ? porque entiendo lo haces usando jquery o similar. Entonces para enviar los datos al servidor usas $.ajax, no se si el problema es como crear esto visualmente o como registrarlo

Comment: mi problema es como registrarlos debido a que se debe crear un nuevo registo en cada fila

Comment: y el + es un boton comun y corriente el cual me crera esos input

Comment: Pero con un input comun y corriente no implementas lo que quieres hacer. Debes adicionar javascript (o jquery) que cree los controles o ese template cada vez que lo presiones. Todos esos datos dinamicos se puede enviar al servidor pero deberas usar $.ajax de jquery o algun framework similar